# Creating a spec helper in rubymotion

Tags: specs, rubymotion

I have some common methods used in a couple different specs, I want to extract them to some place like a spec helper that is accessible from all specs.  Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is something that sorta quacks like a spec_helper.

```rb
# _spec_helper.rb

module SpecHelper
  ::App::Persistence = {}

  # global `before :each` ish
  def self.extended(base)
    base.before do
      ::App::Persistence.clear
    end
  end

  def foo_helper
  end
end
```

And then use it:

```rb
# my_view_spec.rb

describe "MyView" do
  extend SpecHelper

  before do
    foo_helper
  end
  ...
```

Two things to bear in mind:

1. Spec helper file is named in such way that it gets loaded first (leading underscore)
2. When running individual specs (e.g. `files=my_view_spec.rb`) helper file must go along - `files=spec/my_view_spec.rb,spec/_spec_helper.rb`

Comment: I used this solution to solve a slightly different problem, so thanks  very much for this!  I hope something "official" like this eventually finds its way into Rubymotion.

Answer (score 0):

I just throw my common methods used in specs as they are (not encapsulated in a `Module` or anything) in a **spec/support/utilities.rb** file and Rubymotion seems to pick them up fine, though I don't know if this is the "proper" way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

According to current http://www.rubymotion.com/developer-center/articles/testing/#_spec_helpers

> Spec helpers are created under the spec/helpers directory of a RubyMotion project. An example could be spec/helpers/extension.rb.